# Execute code from text input in countdown function

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

In the following code I want to make a text input field (for a date) which gets executed so that the countdown timer is set to that value and starts counting - for example after clicking "OK" button. I don't really know how to modify the first variable in order to do that.

```
<script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("May 25, 2018 11:30:00").getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Pozostało: </br>" + days + " Dni, </br>" + hours + "g : " + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s";
        document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = "45px";
        document.getElementById("demo").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "#4783bf";
        document.getElementById("demo").style.textAlign ="center"; 
        // If the count down is finished, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Thank you for all the advice!

Comment: As I understand, you want to add an input Date field. After clicking Ok button, it will show the different time, right?

Comment: Hello, 
exactly, input data field which after klicking OK executes the implemented date and starts counting down from that date.

Comment: You use Datetimepicker or just input field with the specific format?

Comment: Datetimepicker would be maybe a better solution because you can't introduce the date in a wrong way. However, I don't really know how to create it either.

Comment: Looking forward to see it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle [start timer on click of button](https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/zzLf1Lzr/)

I have entered this date in textbox :- May 26, 2017 01:30:00

```js
function startTimer(){
var dateEntered = document.getElementById("txtDate").value;
// Set the date we're counting down to
//May 26, 2017 01:30:00
var countDownDate = new Date(dateEntered).getTime();
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();
// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;
// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
// Display the result in the element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Pozostało: </br>" + days + " Dni, </br>" + hours + "g : " + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s";
document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = "45px";
document.getElementById("demo").style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "#4783bf";
document.getElementById("demo").style.textAlign ="center"; 
// If the count down is finished, write some text
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDate"/>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="startTimer();">
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first, you need to download datetimepicker library.
https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

And then, following this. Remember to change the path of css and jquery files.

```
<link href="~/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>    
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" />
    <input type="button" value="Ok" id="btOk" />   
    <p id="demo" />
</body>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">      
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btOk').click(function () {

                var currentDate = $('#datetimepicker').val();

                var countDownDate = new Date(currentDate).getTime();                
                // Update the count down every 1 second
                var x = setInterval(function () {
                    // Get todays date and time
                    var now = new Date().getTime();
                    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
                    var distance = countDownDate - now;
                    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Pozostało: </br>" + days + " Dni, </br>" + hours + "g : " + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s";
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = "45px";
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "#4783bf";
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.textAlign = "center";
                    // If the count down is finished, write some text
                    if (distance < 0) {
                        clearInterval(x);
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you just explain quickly how to set up this library and change the paths?

Comment: @kub4w0: Oh, it's very simple. The first, you need to download the library. Extract and you copy jquery.datetimepicker.css and jquery.datetimepicker.min.js files to folder that you want to put. And then, set the specific path. Done!

Comment: @kub4w0: You can visit these links to refer, my friend: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp